# Run spring boot shell as daemon

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-shell

I have an Spring boot web-application with an interactive shell for configuration. I want to run my app as daemon to start server. When I run it normally using `java -jar app.jar` I get an interactive shell and also I can connect to server using web-browser. but sometimes I want to run it as background on a VPS.

When I run it using `nohub` with a bash script like following it run but not as daemon and when I close SSH it stop working.

```
#!/bin/sh
nohup java -jar /web/server.jar &
```

When I run it as service using `ln -s /var/jar-file /etc/init.d/app` and call `service app start` it get error and couldn't run.

When I run it using `java -jar app.jar > /var/log/app.log 2>&1` it starts well but by closing the SSH it stop.

Comment: Strange. `nohup` should've worked. What did you mean by your process not running as daemon when using nohup? Do you see the live application logs in terminal?

Comment: I see terminal waiting for my input without showing output logs @AkhilBojedla

Comment: Strange indeed. It is possible that you are not seeing your prompt because your command is still delivering stderr messages to your console. Try using `> logs.txt 2>&1 </dev/null &` at the end instead of `&`

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to disable the interactive shell with:

```
spring.shell.interactive.enabled=false
```